# Can any one provide me some idea about creating generic framework for wcf client by using factory patterns?

Tags: .net, wcf, factory-pattern, wcf-client

In my work environment I came across a requirement to create framework for client proxy using factory patterns ,so that actual clients instead of adding service reference to service they use this framework. As I don't have much knowledge can anyone provide some idea or useful links for the same.

How about using "**ChannelFactory**" in framework? or framework should have service reference?(My framework should make use of channelfactory/proxy)

thank you..

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for `ChannelFactory<TChannel>.CreateChannel` method. This allows for Creating a channel of a specified type to a specified endpoint address.

This is one of the ways to create a proxy for WCF Services. A very basic example is as shown below

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;


[ServiceContract()]
interface IService
{
    [OperationContract()]
     string GetData(string inputString);
}

public class ConcreteService : IService
{
    public string GetData(String inputString) 
    {
        return "you enetered :" + inputString;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Create a channel factory.
        BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

        EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/ConcreteService/Ep1");

        ChannelFactory<IMath> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

        // Create a channel.
        IService wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        string output = wcfClient1.GetData("abc");
        ((IClientChannel)wcfClient1).Close();

      }

}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I just want to know whether ChannelFactory will be helpful?.I want WCF client with factory patterns.

Comment: Channel factory does require only the Interface which service is implementing and you do not need to add Service reference to the Service.